# Why do enaml checkbox not display their state when window not in focus?

Tags: python, enaml

See the screen shots below of the Employee example from the enaml distribution.

The checkbox does not show it's selected value when the window loses focus.
I've seen this behavior in my code and now I see the example also has this problem.

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That behavior is outside of Enaml's control. It looks like something Qt is doing on its own to try to blend end with the platform look-and-feel.

To be clear, the checkbox *does* show its state, the check mark is just a very light gray.

Comment: You are right, I didn't look close enough.  Maybe I can experiment with look and feel somehow.  Anyone have suggestions on where to look?

Comment: I see there is an QApplication::setStyle function.  Will dig and see how python can create the style.

Comment: Enaml itself has a style sheet system.  Seems better to start there.